# CouchDB - view recursivity

Tags: couchdb

I have a question about querying CouchDB. 
I have a query that generates a set of outputs. These outputs are also the result of another query.
I want to define a CouchDB view permitting to get all the outputs (and the inputs of a specific document). Is it possible to get the results of a map function and consider them as un input of another map function ?

In SPARQL, I have do this query, it is modeled as follow :
SELECT ?linkedAction
WHERE { ?action nova:hasOutput ``doc-02-10-C''. 
            ?action (nova:hasInput/^nova:hasOutput)* ?linkedAction. 
                }
Is it possible to do that in map/reduce ?

### Best Regards.

Amin

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Couch-Incarnate](https://github.com/afters/Couch-Incarnate).

Or use Cloudant [chained mapreduce views](http://support.cloudant.com/customer/portal/articles/359310-chained-mapreduce-views) ([hopefully it will be integrated in CouchDB](http://blog.cloudant.com/the-future-of-couchdb/)).

Answer (score 0):

No, each view index is completely isolated from other views. (and other databases for that matter) CouchDB's incremental view updates would be impossible to keep efficient when changes from one view can affect another. You'll need to perform this kind of additional processing in your application layer.